# How can I Implement Search Query in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to implement a search function in my application based on these tables.

**I have 5 fields on search page**

1. Input box - Keywords or any word in the title
2. Author - Select Box (author_id will be passed to the function as value)
3. Category Name - Select Box (category_id will be passed to the function as value)
4. themonth - Select Box from 1 - 12
5. theyear - Select Box from 2000 - 2012

**I want to create a search query from based upon these rules,**

1. Results array will be sorted by `insights`.`read_time`, (how many times the article has been read)
2. Only want to get the `article`.`article_id`

**Pre-mature working working example is here**

I am running following query to get but it is not complete
https://leading-people.com/search

> SELECT `article`.`article_id` FROM `article` WHERE
>   `article`.`is_active` = '1' AND (`content` LIKE '%%' OR `title` LIKE
>   '%%' OR `tags` LIKE '%%') UNION ALL  SELECT `article`.`article_id`
>   FROM `keywords` INNER JOIN `article` WHERE `article`.`is_active` = '1'
>   AND (`article`.`article_id` = `keywords`.`article_id` AND
>   `keywords`.`keywordtext` LIKE '%%')

TABLE `article`
COLUMNS

- `article_id` (PRIMARY)
- `is_active`
- `title`
- `themonth`
- `theyear`

TABLE `article_author`

Comments: This table is just for reference author details is in another table. So these id(s) are just for reference.

COLUMNS

- `article_author_id` (PRIMARY)
- `author_id`
- `article_id`

TABLE `article_categories`

Comments: This table is just for reference categories details is in another table. So these id(s) are just for reference.

COLUMNS

- `article_categories_id` (PRIMARY)
- `article_id`
- `categories_id`

TABLE `insights`

Comments: This table is just for reference categories details is in another table. So these id(s) are just for reference.

COLUMNS

- `insights_id` (PRIMARY)
- `article_id`
- `read_time`

TABLE `keyword`

Comments: This table is just for reference categories details is in another table. So these id(s) are just for reference.

COLUMNS

- `keyword_id` (PRIMARY)
- `article_id`
- `keywordtext`

Hope! I've formatted it correctly so everyone can understand!

Comment: You should really look at fulltext search for this; queries with `LIKE '%blah%'` will never be able to take advantage of indexes and they will be really slow as the dataset grows.  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for 6,7 hours, I was amazed that it was so simple :-(

Here is the solution that I came up with

> SELECT `article`.`article_id` FROM `article` WHERE $cond (`content` LIKE '%$term%' OR `title` LIKE '%$term%' OR `tags` LIKE '%$term%')
>           AND `article`.`article_id` IN (SELECT `article_categories`.`article_id` FROM `article_categories` WHERE `categories_id` LIKE '$cat') AND `article`.`article_id` IN (SELECT `article_author`.`article_id` FROM `article_author` WHERE `author_id` LIKE '$author')
>
> UNION ALL SELECT `article`.`article_id` FROM `keywords` INNER JOIN
>   `article` WHERE $cond (`article`.`article_id` =
>   `keywords`.`article_id` AND `keywords`.`keyword` LIKE '%$term%')      AND
>   `article`.`article_id` IN (SELECT `article_categories`.`article_id`
>   FROM `article_categories` WHERE `categories_id` LIKE '$cat') AND
>   `article`.`article_id` IN (SELECT `article_author`.`article_id` FROM
>   `article_author` WHERE `author_id` LIKE '$author')

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in your quest:

```
$keyword_mysql= mysql_real_escape_string($keyword);

SELECT article.article_id
FROM article 
LEFT JOIN insights ON(article.article_id=insights.article_id)
WHERE article.is_active = '1' AND (content LIKE '%{$keyword_mysql}%' OR title LIKE '%{$keyword_mysql}%' OR tags LIKE '%{$keyword_mysql}%') 
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT article.article_id 
FROM keywords INNER JOIN article WHERE article.is_active = '1' AND (article.article_id = keywords.article_id AND keywords.keywordtext LIKE '%{$keyword_mysql}%')
LEFT JOIN insights ON(article.article_id=insights.article_id)
ORDER BY insights.read_time
```

You also could escape underscores and percents in $keyword_mysql with a backslash.

I'm not sure whether the ordering will work if the read_time column is not part of the selected fields. If not, add it to the selected fields and ORDER BY read_time instead.

Comment: Provided SQL doesn't contains anything for category or author, Please help me to complete the query!